# Demonstration of relation between geodesics and FLRW metric

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, geodesic, general-relativity

I am reading a book of General Relativity and I am stuck on a demonstration. If I consider the FLRW metric as :

$\text{d}\tau^2=\text{d}t^2-a(t)^2\bigg[\dfrac{\text{d}r^2}{1-kr^2}+r^2(\text{d}\theta^2+\text{sin}^2\theta\text{d}\phi^2)\bigg]$

with $g_{tt}=1$, $\quad g_{rr}=\dfrac{a(t)^2}{1-kr^2}$ and $\quad g_{\theta\theta}=\dfrac{g_{\phi\phi}}{\text{sin}^2\theta}=a(t)^2 r^2$

It is said in this book that, despite of the utility of comoving coordinates, the dependance of time in scale factor $a(t)$ can be better understood if we consider a set of coordinates called "Free Fall coordinates" and noted $(\tilde{x}^\mu, \mu=0,1,2,3)$ with a metric locally Lorentzian near to the origin $\tilde{x}^{\mu}=0$ :

$g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+\dfrac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta}(0)\tilde{x}^{\alpha}\tilde{x}^{\beta}+\,.......\quad\text{(eq1)}$

with $\eta_{00}=-\eta_{11}=-\eta_{22}=-\eta_{33}=1\quad\quad$ and $\eta_{\mu\neq\nu}=0$

and $g_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta}=\dfrac{\partial^2 g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial \tilde{x}^{\alpha}\partial \tilde{x}^{\beta}}$

Moreover, one takes the expression of classic geodesics :

$\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\tau}\bigg(g_{\mu\nu}(x)\dfrac{\text{d}x^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau}\bigg)-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial g_{\lambda\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\dfrac{\text{d}x^{\lambda}}{\text{d}\tau}\dfrac{\text{d}x^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau}=0\quad\quad\mu=0,1,2,3\quad \text{(eq2)}$

The author says that, by applying $\text{(eq1)}$ into the relation $\text{(eq2)}$, one gets, at first order, the following relation :

$\dfrac{\text{d}^2 \tilde{x}^{\alpha}}{\text{d}\tau^2} = -\eta^{\alpha\gamma}\bigg[g_{\mu\gamma,\nu\beta}-\dfrac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu,\gamma\beta}\bigg]\tilde{x}^{\beta}\dfrac{\text{d}\tilde{x}^{\mu}}{\text{d}\tau}\dfrac{\text{d}\tilde{x}^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau}\quad\quad\text{(eq3)}$

**I can't manage to obtain the $\text{eq(3)}$ from $\text{eq(1)}$ and $\text{eq(2)}$, if someone could help me for the details of the demonstration, this would be nice.**

**For the moment, if I put the definition of $g_{\nu\mu}$ into $\text{eq(2)}$,  I get :**

$\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\tau}\bigg(g_{\mu\nu}(x)\dfrac{\text{d}x^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau}\bigg)=\bigg(\dfrac{\text{d}g_{\mu\nu}}{\text{d}\tau}\bigg)\,\dfrac{\text{d}x^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau}+g_{\mu\nu}\dfrac{\text{d}^2x^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau^2}\quad\quad \text{eq(4)}$

If I separate the two terms on RHS on $\text{eq(4)}$ :

$\bigg(\dfrac{\text{d}g_{\mu\nu}}{\text{d}\tau}\bigg)\,\dfrac{\text{d}x^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau}=\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\tau}\bigg(\eta_{\mu\nu}+\dfrac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta}(0)\tilde{x}^{\alpha}\tilde{x}^{\beta}\bigg)\dfrac{\text{d}x^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau}=$

$\dfrac{1}{2}\,g_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta}(0)\bigg[\dfrac{\text{d}\tilde{x}^{\alpha}}{\text{d}\tau}\,\tilde{x}^{\beta}+\tilde{x}^{\alpha}\,\dfrac{\text{d}\tilde{x}^{\beta}}{\text{d}\tau}\bigg]\dfrac{\text{d}x^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau}=$

$g_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta}(0)\bigg[\dfrac{\text{d}\tilde{x}^{\alpha}}{\text{d}\tau}\,\tilde{x}^{\beta}\bigg]\dfrac{\text{d}x^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau}$

Concerning the second term on RHS of $\text{eq(4)}$, maybe I could write :

$g_{\mu\nu}\dfrac{\text{d}^2x^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau^2}=\eta_{\mu\nu}\dfrac{\text{d}^2x^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau^2}$ by neglecting the term $\dfrac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta}(0)\tilde{x}^{\alpha}\tilde{x}^{\beta}$ in the expression of $g_{\mu\nu}$.

Another problem, How can I transform the second term on LHS of $\text{(eq2)}$ :

$-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial g_{\lambda\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\dfrac{\text{d}x^{\lambda}}{\text{d}\tau}\dfrac{\text{d}x^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau}\quad\quad \text{eq(5)}$ ??

Indeed, it seems that we can deduce from this term the wanted term :

$\dfrac{1}{2}\,\eta^{\alpha\gamma}\,g_{\mu\nu,\gamma\beta}\tilde{x}^{\beta}\dfrac{\text{d}\tilde{x}^{\mu}}{\text{d}\tau}\dfrac{\text{d}\tilde{x}^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau}$

But $\tilde{x}$ coordinates ("Free Fall coordinates") appear in this last expression instead of "Comobile coordinates" $x^{\mu}$ into $\text{eq(5)}$ , so I don't know how to get it ?

Finally, to do the link between "Fre Fall coordinates" and "Comoving coordinates", can I write :

$g_{\mu\nu}\text{d}x^{\mu}\text{d}x^{\nu}=\eta_{\alpha\beta}\text{d}\tilde{x}^{\alpha}\text{d}\tilde{x}^{\beta}$ ??

Any help is welcome

**UPDATE 1 :** You can find below 2 image captures resuming the different equations (mostly important eq(4.4), eq(4.5); eq(4.6) and eq(4.87)) :

[image: page1]
[image: page2]

**UPDATE 2 :** Thanks for your demo. Just a last question, how do you do the link between the definition of coordinates called "Free Fall coordinates" and noted $(\tilde{x}^\mu, \mu=0,1,2,3)$ :

$g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+\dfrac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta}(0)\tilde{x}^{\alpha}\tilde{x}^{\beta}+\,.......\quad\text{(eq1)}$

and the comoving coordinates that you use into your following start point :

$\frac{\partial g_{\lambda\nu}}{\partial x^\mu} = g_{\lambda\nu,\mu\beta} x^\beta$

I mean, you don't use $\tilde{x}$ notation in your demontsration, that makes me confused.

Regards

Comment: Friedmann–Lemaître–Robertson–Walker (FLRW) metric is an exact solution of Einstein's field equations of general relativity

Comment: What book is it?

Comment: -@magma You can see it on ftp://nozdr.ru/biblio/kolxo3/P/PGrc/Rich%20J.%20Fundamentals%20of%20Cosmology%20(2ed.,%20Springer,%202010)(ISBN%203642027997)(O)(332s)_PGrc_.pdf (page 154 on book itself and page 163/332 on pdf viewer)

Comment: There is a mistake/typo in the metric components: you are missing the minus sign in front of $g_{rr}$ and $g_{\theta\theta}$

Comment: exact, as you can see, I took at the beginning the conventions of the image captures at the end of my message. But I think this hasn't got consequences on the demo wanted (eq (4.87)).

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\frac{\partial g_{\lambda\nu}}{\partial x^\mu} = g_{\lambda\nu,\mu\beta} x^\beta$$ and $$ \frac{d}{d\tau}\left(g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}\right) = \eta_{\mu\nu}\frac{d^2x^\nu}{d\tau^2}+\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta} x^\alpha x^\beta \frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}\right)\\ =\eta_{\mu\nu}\frac{d^2x^\nu}{d\tau^2} + g_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta} x^{\alpha} \frac{dx^\beta}{d\tau}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau} + O(x^2)$$ where we used symmetry in the last line. So plugging into the geodesic equation gives
$$
\eta_{\mu\nu}\frac{d^2x^\nu}{d\tau^2} = \frac{1}{2}g_{\lambda\nu,\mu\beta}x^\beta\frac{dx^\lambda}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}-g_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta}x^\alpha\frac{d x^\beta}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}.
$$

Contracting both sides, doing some index relabeling to factor out the x's, and introducing the answer's awkward minus sign placement, $$ \frac{d^2 x^\alpha}{d\tau^2} =-\eta^{\alpha \mu}\left(g_{\mu\nu,\alpha\beta}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\beta\nu,\mu\alpha}\right)x^{\alpha}\frac{dx^\beta}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}.$$

Finally, using the symmetry in the first pair and second pair of indices in the first term,
$$ \frac{d^2 x^\alpha}{d\tau^2} =-\eta^{\alpha \mu}\left(g_{\nu\mu,\beta\alpha}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\beta\nu,\mu\alpha}\right)x^{\alpha}\frac{dx^\beta}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau} $$
which I believe is a relabeling of dummy indices away from the answer.

Comment: -@spaceisdarkgreen : thanks, could you take a look in my **Update 2** for a last precision ?

Comment: @youpilat13 I don't use the ~ only because it's a waste of time to write it. I should have mentioned this. I do not use comoving coordinates as a starting point (though I'm not sure why you'd infer that... I'm just using generic notation while the approximations used imply the coordinates must be the free fall)... the entire calculation is done with the free fall coordinates

Comment: ok, understood, I will award you, regards